# JBoss not booting: Failed to parse configuration

Tags: docker, jboss, wildfly

I have a docker image (docker version 17.09) for a java product that is using jboss. When, I am installing the product in normal course, it is deploying fine. However, when I am starting the Docker image of the same, it is giving below error:

```
06:51:36,621 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0055: Caught exception during boot: org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.ConfigurationPersistenceException: WFLYCTL0085: Failed to parse configuration
        at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:131) [wildfly-controller-2.1.15.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.15.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:362) [wildfly-server-2.1.15.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.15.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:301) [wildfly-controller-2.1.15.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.15.Final-redhat-1]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_121]
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: WFLYCTL0083: Failed to load module org.jboss.as.threads
        at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.ExtensionXml.parseExtensions(ExtensionXml.java:155) [wildfly-controller-2.1.15.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.15.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml$DefaultExtensionHandler.parseExtensions(StandaloneXml.java:126) [wildfly-server-2.1.15.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.15.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml_Legacy.readServerElement_1_4(StandaloneXml_Legacy.java:424) [wildfly-server-2.1.15.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.15.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml_Legacy.readElement(StandaloneXml_Legacy.java:135) [wildfly-server-2.1.15.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.15.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:100) [wildfly-server-2.1.15.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.15.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:49) [wildfly-server-2.1.15.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.15.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:110) [staxmapper-1.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.parseDocument(XMLMapperImpl.java:69) [staxmapper-1.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:123) [wildfly-controller-2.1.15.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.15.Final-redhat-1]
        ... 3 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: WFLYCTL0309: Legacy extension 'org.jboss.as.threads' is not supported on servers running this version. The extension is only supported for use by hosts running a previous release in a mixed-version managed domain
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) [rt.jar:1.8.0_121]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) [rt.jar:1.8.0_121]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.ExtensionXml.parseExtensions(ExtensionXml.java:147) [wildfly-controller-2.1.15.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.15.Final-redhat-1]
        ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: WFLYCTL0309: Legacy extension 'org.jboss.as.threads' is not supported on servers running this version. The extension is only supported for use by hosts running a previous release in a mixed-version managed domain
        at org.jboss.as.controller.extension.AbstractLegacyExtension.initializeParsers(AbstractLegacyExtension.java:87) [wildfly-controller-2.1.15.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.15.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.ExtensionXml.loadModule(ExtensionXml.java:183) [wildfly-controller-2.1.15.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.15.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.ExtensionXml.access$000(ExtensionXml.java:69) [wildfly-controller-2.1.15.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.15.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.ExtensionXml$1.call(ExtensionXml.java:127) [wildfly-controller-2.1.15.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.15.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.ExtensionXml$1.call(ExtensionXml.java:124) [wildfly-controller-2.1.15.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.15.Final-redhat-1]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [rt.jar:1.8.0_121]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_121]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_121]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_121]
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320) [jboss-threads-2.2.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.2.1.Final-redhat-1]

06:51:36,639 FATAL [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0056: Server boot has failed in an unrecoverable manner; exiting. See previous messages for details.
06:51:36,701 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYSRV0050: JBoss EAP 7.0.6.GA (WildFly Core 2.1.15.Final-redhat-1) stopped in 24ms
```

I searched on net and found a related article:

> https://github.com/jboss-dockerfiles/modeshape/issues/2.

However, I didn't understand it as my Java knowledge is very less.
Any help or suggestion would be helpful

Please help.
Nishant

Comment: What version of WildFly or JBoss EAP are you running locally? It looks like you're using an old, possibly unsupported, configuration for JBoss EAP 7.

Comment: Yes, I also figured out the same. I rebuilt all the dependent Docker images again and issue got resolved. However, the mystery remained that from where it was getting the old configuration file.